# change url of admin panel in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

i want to create my own custom admin-url in wordpress... how can i do?
for open admin panel we write http://yoursite.com/wp-admin or http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php

if i wrote in .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^login$ http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php [NC,L]
```

and i write http://yoursite.com/login in url then it will redirect to the admin login urls.

ok this will works nicely.. and suppose some one write wp-admin or wp-login.php in url then it will directely redirect to the home page of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [stealth login plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stealth-login/) for that if you want a quick solution

Comment: ok this will works... but my condition is that suppose some one write wp-admin or wp-login.php in url then it will directely redirect to the home page of my site.

Comment: if someone is trying to break into your wp, why would want to 'nicely' redirect them to your home page? just let them hit the wall and leave them there... why bother?

Comment: ok i doesn't want to redirect.. but if i am write wp-login.php then i will not display the login page.. it might be display like "Error in page."

Comment: did you try that? I believe WP should indeed show an error message (wp themed) by default.

Comment: yes i tried.. it will show error message... please give me the solution. how could i do it?